# How to build next.js with rollup?

Tags: next.js, rollup

I am going to build nextjs with rollup.
I couldn't find help doc or other source about rollup nextjs.

Here is my progress.
**Please help me with sample code how to rollup nextjs.**

I can build next.js with rollup. It is only one file bundle.js. **How to start server using this file?**

-rollup.config.js

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import path from "path";

import pkg from "./package.json";

const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"];
const babelConfig = path.resolve(__dirname, "babel.config.js");

export default {
  input: "pages/index.js",
  output: [
    {
      format: "es",
      exports: "named",
      file: 'dist/bundle.js',
      sourcemap: 'inline'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    babel({
      extensions,
      babelrc: false,
      babelHelpers: "bundled",
      configFile: babelConfig,
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
    }),
    resolve({ extensions }),
    commonjs({ extensions }),
  ],
  external: [
    "next/app",
    "effector-react/ssr",
    ...Object.keys(Object.assign({}, pkg.dependencies, pkg.peerDependencies)),
  ],
};
```

-babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

  const presets = [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        loose: true,
        modules: false,
        shippedProposals: true,
        targets: {
          node: "12",
          browsers: [
            "last 2 Chrome versions",
            "last 2 Firefox versions",
            "last 2 Safari versions",
            "last 2 Edge versions",
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ];

  const plugins = [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

-package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build-next": "next build",
    "start-next": "next start",
    "build-rollup": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "effector": "^21.8.11",
    "effector-next": "^1.2.0",
    "effector-react": "^21.3.2",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "systemjs": "^6.13.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to consider add more details in your question @v08nike. If you want to add `rollup` in your `nextjs` app then you need to install it first `npm install --save-dev rollup rollup-plugin-node-resolve rollup-plugin-commonjs rollup-plugin-replace` I guess which you have already done.